# Excel: How to assign value to txt and sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, string, rating

I have a file with several football player ratings: `***, **, *` or x.

`***` means a performance of 3, `**= 2`; `*= 1` and `x` if the player didn't play.

I want to have a sum at the end of the row to see the performance of each player.

File looks like this:

```
      game1   game2  Game3
Toni   **      ***     x
Jean   **      **      *
James  *       **     *
```

Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You simple need to count an occurrence of "*" in a range like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B2:D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:D2, "*","")))
```

For the details how it works take a look: [How to count characters in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/15/how-to-count-characters-excel/)